# What is a Hibernate Business Object? DTO?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I've come across some terminology I've not seen before and wanted to make sure I have the correct understanding.

I'm working on learning Spring, thus far I've only used basic POJOs with annotations that reference the Id / persistence requirements.

I was working from a tutorial that used DTOs, I read a little about the pros and cons and it seemed to be something that should be considered for high volumes.  I ditched the DTO.

I've now come across an example which specifies that the `object must contain d​escription​ and a d​ate ​fields and should be stored in a database ​using a hibernate business object.`

My first approach to get a working system is to use a POJO with annotations, after re-reading this I wonder if it means I should use a DTO instead?

Could someone shed some light on the meaning please?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [POJOs populated by Hibernate are entities, business objects or data transfer objects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177082/pojos-populated-by-hibernate-are-entities-business-objects-or-data-transfer-obj)

Answer (score 2):

In this context the POJOs you're creating would be considered "Business Objects" when annotated with JPA.

DTOs or Business Objects could be implemented as POJOs.

BO is just an older term for persisted objects (that's fallen from favour?)